# Get Wifi Address Problem

Tags: iphone, sockets

I try to get ip address using asyncsocket framework. When do it via ethernet cable the following method works good. 
But when try to get ip address using wifi access point it returns nil.

Here is a method:

```
- (NSData *)wifiAddress
```

{
    // On iPhone, WiFi is always "en0"

```
NSData *result = nil;

struct ifaddrs *addrs;
const struct ifaddrs *cursor;

if ((getifaddrs(&addrs) == 0))
{
    cursor = addrs;
    while (cursor != NULL)
    {
        NSLog(@"cursor->ifa_name = %s", cursor->ifa_name);

        if (strcmp(cursor->ifa_name, "en0") == 0)
        {
            if (cursor->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET)
            {
                struct sockaddr_in *addr = (struct sockaddr_in *)cursor->ifa_addr;
                NSLog(@"cursor->ifa_addr = %s", inet_ntoa(addr->sin_addr));

                result = [NSData dataWithBytes:addr length:sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)];
                cursor = NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                cursor = cursor->ifa_next;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cursor = cursor->ifa_next;
        }
    }
    freeifaddrs(addrs);
}

return result;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The issue we had was that an exact match on en0 would not always return the wifi address.  We have something similar to the following.  Hope this helps.

```
NSString* wifiIp = [NetUtils getLocalAddress:@"en"];

+ (NSString *) getLocalAddress:(NSString*) interface
{
    NSString *address = nil;
    struct ifaddrs *interfaces = NULL;
    struct ifaddrs *temp_addr = NULL;
    int success = 0;

    success = getifaddrs(&interfaces);
    if (success == 0)
    {
        temp_addr = interfaces;
        while(temp_addr != NULL)
        {
            if(temp_addr->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET)
            {
                NSRange range = [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:temp_addr->ifa_name] rangeOfString : interface];

                if(range.location != NSNotFound)
                {
                    address = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)temp_addr->ifa_addr)->sin_addr)];
                }
            }

            temp_addr = temp_addr->ifa_next;
        }
    }

    freeifaddrs(interfaces);

    return address;
}
```

Comment: What should I insert in (NSString*) interface parameter?

Comment: We just use "en" so anything with "en" (e.g. en0, en1) will be caught.